# How to get csv reader to ignore commas within braces (curly, square, & angle)?

Tags: python, csv

I have comma separated values that contain commas within nested braces. Specifically, I'll have an input of comma separated C++11 objects.

For example, here's an input:

`std::vector<int>{32, 45, 10}, std::array<std::string, 5>{"a", "bc", "def", "ghij", "whoa, this is, a toughie"}, 8, "foo, bar", {"initializer-list?", "no problem!", "(hopefully...)"}`

Here's my desired output:

```
[
    'std::vector<int>{32, 45, 10}',
    'std::array<std::string, 5>{"a", "bc", "def", "ghij", "whoa, this is, a toughie"}',
    '8',
    'foo, bar',
    '{"initializer-list?", "no problem!", "(hopefully...)"}'
]
```

But python's csv gives me:

```
[
    'std::vector<int>{32',
    '45',
    '10}',
    'std::array<std::string',
    '5>{"a"',
    '"bc"',
    '"def"',
    '"ghij"',
    '"whoa',
    'this is',
    'a toughie"}',
    '8',
    'foo, bar', # at least this one works :/
    '{"initializer-list?"',
    '"no problem!"',
    '"(hopefully...)"}'
]
```

How can I customize the csv module to handle these cases?

Comment: What is the c++11 tag for?

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: @Tim sorry about that, guess it's just instinct from asking c++ related questions. removed now!

Comment: @Ben but regular expressions can't recognize nested things right? I could have `std::map<std::vector<int>, std::map<int, std::string>>`

Comment: So i guess i misunderstood what you wanted for your output, perhaps you should add the exact output you want from the above example.

Comment: @Ben ok, well the first input is formatted as the output I want.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Wait, i am confused, what is the original input then?

Comment: @Ben alright I cleared things up!

Comment: It would've been amazing if python csv would turn out to be a c++ parser.

Comment: @popo well, all I want are nestable braces, i figured since it handles quotes fine it could handle braces as well. the c++ arguments are more of an example.

Comment: Try pyparsing to do this

Comment: @Colt I think that's the only way to get it done in a pythonic way. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a regex to split each line, and then clean it a bit afterwards

```
import re
a = r'std::vector<int>{32, 45, 10}, std::array<std::string, 5>{"a", "bc", "def", "ghij", "whoa, this is, a toughie"}, 8, "foo, bar", {"initializer-list?", "no     problem!", "(hopefully...)"}'

# split on occurrences of "}, s"
results = re.split('},\s+s', a)
```

**Note:** splitting will remove `}` from the end of each string (except the last), and will remove `s` from each string except the first.

### Edit:

Wanted to take a shot at solving this, and came up with the following (which assumes the strings don't have single characters from the set `{,},",<,>`). You could remove the `<,>` cases by being more specific with a look ahead for a cpp declaration.

```
a = r'std::vector<int>{32, 45, 10}, std::array<std::string, 5>{"a", "bc", "def", "ghij", "whoa, this is, a toughie"}, 8, "foo, bar", {"initializer-list?", "no problem!", "(hopefully...)"}'

l_braces = {"{", "<"}
r_braces = {"}", ">"}

def split(s):
  brace_count = 0
  quote_count = 0
  breaks = []

  for i, c in enumerate(s):

    if c == '"':
      quote_count += 1
      if quote_count % 2 == 1:
        brace_count += 1
      else:
        brace_count -= 1

    if (c in l_braces):
      brace_count += 1

    if (c in r_braces):
      brace_count -= 1

    if (c == ",") and (brace_count == 0):
      breaks.append(i)

  pieces = []

  lag = 0
  for b in breaks:
    pieces.append(s[lag:b].strip())
    lag = b+1

  pieces.append(s[breaks[-1]+1:].strip())
  return pieces

print(split(a))
```

Where `print(split(a))` will print the following...

```
['std::vector<int>{32, 45, 10}',
 'std::array<std::string, 5>{"a", "bc", "def", "ghij", "whoa, this is, a toughie"}',
 '8',
 '"foo, bar"',
 '{"initializer-list?", "no problem!", "(hopefully...)"}']
```

Comment: well I don't think it'll work since c++allows nested brackets, for ex/ `{a, {b, c}, d, e}` so I need a way to handle any and all of these cases

Comment: if your cpp arrays/vectors don't include cpp code strings, you could split on something like `re.split('},\s+std::(?:vector|array)', a)`, otherwise it looks like your left writing a specific DSL parser

Comment: @BrianRodriguez took another shot

Comment: Great that works! I'll play with it too and see where it gets me. For now though, I'll leave the question unanswered since there doesn't actually seem to be one for my specific question

Answer (score 0):

You're CSV module just seperates values when it finds a comma. It doesn't care about other symbols.

To achive a speraration the way you want it, you would have to extend the module logic in a way that it detects opening brackets such as "{".
When it finds an opening bracket, all comma symbols should be ignored until a closing-bracket was found.

That way you should get the desired output.

Comment: well I was hoping for a more pythonic way to do this, but if none exists then that answers my question too